# Auto calculating columns in a sql table based on prevoius row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using sql server as back-end for developing my application in asp.net c#. Now i need to create a table with an auto calculating column(closing balance) as shown below:

```
Date    in stock    out stock   closing balance
2/3/2013    0             0          0
3/3/2013    10            5          5
5/3/2013    10            52        -37
6/3/2013    52            7          8
7/3/2013    6             50        -36
8/3/2013    10            12        -38
```

Here the closing balance for each day depends on the closing balance of the previous day

For Example, today's closing balance=(previous day closing balance+today's instock)-(today's outstock)
When i add a new entry dated 4/3/2013 to the table,the table must be shown as below

```
Date    in stock    out stock   closing balance
2/3/2013    0            0              0
3/3/2013    10           5              5
4/3/2013    20          15             10
5/3/2013    10          52            -32
6/3/2013    52           7             13
7/3/2013    6           50            -31
8/3/2013    10          12            -33
```

i made this using microsoft excel(using formulas),but i need to achieve it using sql server table for my application. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you identify the 'previous day' for any given record? Does your table hold records for only 1 entity?

Comment: Your first table doesn't correspond to a formula

Comment: OP, if you want to enter the row whose date is in between, then your closing balance column should be dynamic, i.e. it is not going to be a column in your table structure.

Comment: It can be easily achieved with SQL Server 2012 but you tagged sql-server-2008 in your question. Without 2012, you need to use cursors in order to get the desired results.

Comment: @dn7123 Not necessary you have to use cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumption**

1.Your table structure is like

```
Date | In Stock | Out Stock
```

2.You will insert a **New Columns** before calculating the `balance`.

3.Date is an `Primary Column` (**Unique + Not NULL**)

Taking the above assumptions:

You have make a **SP** if you want to use in **C#**

1.Create a **temp table** and assigned `Row Number` using **Rank()**

```
select 
rank() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) as [Rank],
t1.[Date],
t1.[in stock],
t1.[out stock]
--,t1.[in stock]-t1.[out stock] balance
into #temp1
from (your table name)
;
```

2.Now you will be using the above `temp table` to get the **Balance**

```
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Rank],
        [Date],
        [in stock],
        [out stock],
        bal=([in stock]-[out stock])
    FROM #temp1
    WHERE [Rank] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        y.[Rank],
        y.[Date],
        y.[in stock],
        y.[out stock],
        x.bal+(y.[in stock]-y.[out stock])
    FROM x INNER JOIN #temp1 AS y
    ON y.[Rank] = x.[Rank] + 1
)
SELECT 
    [Date],
    [in stock],
    [out stock],
    Balance = bal
FROM x
ORDER BY Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d839/6)** where you can verify.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you don't need really need recursion...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetClosingBalance(@Date date) RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal int
    SELECT
        @RetVal = SUM([in stock]) - SUM([out stock])
    FROM
        x
    WHERE
        [Date] <= @Date
    RETURN @RetVal
END

ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN [closing balance] AS (dbo.GetClosingBalance([Date]))
```