# Accumulating in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a query with results like ID, Value. What I want is to get the values in order of their ids and also calculate the accumulated value in another column. take a look at my simplified code:

```
declare @TempTable Table
(
    ID int,
    Value int
)
insert into @TempTable values
(1, 10),
(2, -15),
(3, 12),
(4, 18),
(5, 5)

select t1.ID, t1.Value, SUM(t2.Value) AccValue from @TempTable t1
inner join @TempTable t2 on t1.ID >= t2.ID
group by t1.ID, t1.Value
order by t1.ID




Result:
ID  Value   AccValue
1   10      10
2   -15     -5
3   12      7
4   18      25
5   5       30
```

What I have come up with, is to use inner join between the result and itself for that purpose. But for huge amount of data, it's clearly a low performance issue.

Is there any other alternative to do that?

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive SQL- How can I get this table with a running total?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050660/recursive-sql-how-can-i-get-this-table-with-a-running-total)

Comment: @Hosein **[Please refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955962/auto-calculating-columns-in-a-sql-table-based-on-prevoius-row-data/15969926#15969926)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2012 version, you can use:

```
SELECT
    id,
    Value,
    AccValue = SUM(Value) OVER (ORDER BY ID 
                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                         AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM 
    @TempTable ;
```

For previous versions of SQL-Server, see my answer in this similar question: [Recursive SQL- How can I get this table with a running total?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050660/recursive-sql-how-can-i-get-this-table-with-a-running-total/17051046#17051046), with a **cursor** solution.

Even better, follow the link to the great article by [@Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand), that has a thorough test of various methods to calculate a running total: **[Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)**

Comment: I didn't know of that and thank you. Sorry it's not available in 2008. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. Follow the links to see why a cursor would be the most efficient solution in your version.

Comment: Great solution my friend. It's Complete and works in a completely reasonable time. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for that, I used it with an additional `PARTITION BY` clause required by my use case, it's by far the most readable solution and it's performing nicely.

Comment: @Guillaume86 Yes, efficiency is usually very good with proper indexing, e.g. an `(id) INCLUDE (value)` in this case. Or a `(partition_by_column, id) INCLUDE (value)` if you have `partition by`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
        [ID],
        [Value],
        bal=[Value]
    FROM Table1
    WHERE [ID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        y.[ID],
        y.[Value],
        x.bal+(y.[Value]) as bal
    FROM x INNER JOIN Table1 AS y
    ON y.[ID] = x.[ID] + 1
)
SELECT 
    [ID],
    [Value],
    AccValue= bal
FROM x
order by ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10df7/1)**

Comment: @ypercube: I think we can use Row_Number instead of ID to overcome that issue.

Comment: @Luv: In comparison between your solution and ypercube's, I think his should be faster, because the cursor approach is dynamic and O(n), but the recursive solution is O(n^2). Although it's my guess and I should check if it's accurate or not.

Answer (score 1):

The generic SQL way to do this is with a correlated subquery (at least, I think that is the cleanest way):

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.value)
        from @TempTable t2
        where t2.ID <= t.ID
       ) AccValue
from @TempTable t
```

SQL Server 2012 has a cumulative sum function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.value) over (order by t.id) as AccValue
from @TempTable t
```

Comment: Thanks man. Unfortunately I'm using 2008 R2. Is the subquery solution any different from my inner join, considering the performance?

Comment: @Hosein . . . The best way to check is by comparing the execution plans and the performance.  Both should be reasonable with an index on `t(id, value)`, although I wouldn't be surprised if the subquery performed better.  I prefer the subquery method because I find it more readable and there is not danger of losing any rows from a join.